# How enable FlushModeType.COMMIT in Hibernate with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I'm migrating a JPA application from an old version of EclipseLink to Hibernate 5.4.9.Final.

In EclipseLink, the EntityManager FlushMode was configured to `COMMIT`, via the following property in `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT"/>
```

I try to do the same in Hibernate, and as per the documentation, I use the following property:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT" />
```

but hibernate does not pick it up.

I have to mention that the behaviour needs to remain the same, otherwise I should rewrite the whole application. My `persistence.xml` looks like this:

```xml
...
<persistence-unit name="test">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
  <!--<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>-->

  <class>com.test.Person</class>

  <properties>
    <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT"/>
    <!--<property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="COMMIT"/>-->
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
...
```

In my JUnit Test, I bootstrap JPA as follows:

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test", properties);
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
System.out.println("Underlying Hibernate session flushmode #######         " + session.getFlushMode());
System.out.println("EntityManager flushmode                #######         " + entityManager.getFlushMode());
```

If I run the test with EclipseLink, it shows the EntityManager flushmode `COMMIT` correctly. If I run the test with Hibernate, the EntityManager flushmode incorrectly shows `AUTO`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this functionality was broken under [HHH-13565](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13565). It works in the hibernate 5.4.4.

This is [HHH-13677](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13677)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Well, I guess I’ll wait to be fixed, and have a workaround in the meantime.